# How new int[n]() works?

Tags: c++, initialization, new-operator

I am curious about new `int[n]()` operator, as per my knowledge it uses to initialize the array values to zero which is created using the `new` operator. But I can't use some value in parenthesis like new `int[n](x)` to initialize values to `x`, why I can't do that, What happens at the compiler level when I use `new int[n]()`?

Comment: I think you'll need a separate `std::fill_n(array, n, x);`  And I recommend `std::vector` instead, because it's all around better.

Comment: This behaviour is just what the standard demands. What do you mean exactly by "at the compiler level"? Do you want to see the compiler's source code where it implements initialisers?

Comment: "at compiler level" means, whether it calls the constructor or is there any other way it initializes the array ex. `static storage duration`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int` is a POD and per C++11 you value initialize the array. In the case of `int` it is `0`.

The reason it doesn't work with value in parantheses is because it is not defined. If you insist (for educational reason) you can overload the new operator to do what you want.

You can initialize the array with initializer list though:

```
int* a = new int[10]{10, 6};
```

However it will initialize the first two elements in this example.

Answer (score 2):

`new` invokes a constructor call on `int[n]()`, which is what is setting it to 0. When you call it as `new int[n]`, you are simply **default initializing** the array. Meaning the memory is only allocated, and not set.

`new int[n]()` is **value-initializing** your array, both allocating space and initializing each `int`, like `int()`. This is why it is set to 0, and cannot be set to anything else by invoking `int(x)`; there is no `int` constructor that can use `x` in that way. Calling `int(x)` would be read as a **functional style cast**, and not a constructor of type `int`.